# Show different button text if no content

Tags: php

With this code:

```
<?php if ( $clpr_options->coupon_code_hide ) {
            $button_text = fl_get_option( 'fl_lbl_show_coupon' );
            $button_text = '<i class="icon-lock"></i>' . $button_text;
            $class .= ' coupon-hidden';
            }
         ?>
```

I get a special Text show on a button. Now I would like to show a special button_text if the field `clpr_coupon_code`is empty.

Tried

```
<?php if ( $clpr_options->coupon_code_hide ) {
            $button_text = fl_get_option( 'fl_lbl_show_coupon' );
            $button_text = '<i class="icon-lock"></i>' . $button_text;
            $class .= ' coupon-hidden';

            } else {
            $class .= ' coupon-hidden';
            $meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'clpr_coupon_code', true );} 
            $meta == '';
            $button_text = 'Angebot anzeigen';

            }
         ?>
```

But just getting empty page.

Comment: There's an unwanted `}` after the `get_post_meta()` call - `true );}`, and what is that `$meta == '';` doing?

Comment: removed the `}` the `$meta == ' ';` is checking if meta is empty.

Comment: still not working just stuck

Comment: Check and try my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, as I mentioned in the comment, you got a syntax error here, where there's an *unwanted `}`*:

```
$meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'clpr_coupon_code', true );} // <- that }
```

*(Updated answer — Previous code were removed since they didn't work for you.)*

So if you want to show the special text when `$clpr_options->coupon_code_hide` does <strike>not</strike> evaluate to a `true` and that the field `clpr_coupon_code` is empty; try this:

```
<?php if ( $clpr_options->coupon_code_hide ) {
    $class .= ' coupon-hidden';
    $meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'clpr_coupon_code', true );

    // If clpr_coupon_code is empty.
    if ( ! $meta ) {
        $button_text = 'Angebot anzeigen';
    // If clpr_coupon_code is not empty.
    } else {
        $button_text = fl_get_option( 'fl_lbl_show_coupon' );
        $button_text = '<i class="icon-lock"></i>' . $button_text;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, but unfortunately its not working still shows the content of `$button_text = '<i class="icon-lock"></i>' . $button_text;`all the time

Comment: In that case, then it's probably because `$clpr_options->coupon_code_hide` is always `true` in your tests. Let me update the answer.

Comment: yes `$clpr_options->coupon_code_hide` is always true `$button_Text`sould only change if `clpr_coupon_code`is empty.

Comment: WOW just great. ITS WORKING, thanks a lot. Was just starting to go into the same directions. But just a newbie. Still a long way ;-) Again THANKS

Comment: You're welcome! And it's alright, nobody started as a pro.. just keep on learning and you'll become better in time. :)